# How to Remove input text fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I want to add text fields by clicking on button. It is working but I am unable to remove the text fields by clicking on remove button. Please see the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var i = 1;
function more_fields() {

 i++;
 var objTo = document.getElementById('more_fields')
var divtest = document.createElement("div");
divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+i);
var rdiv = 'removeclass'+i;

divtest.innerHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="comp[]" id="component" 
value="" placeholder="Product" /> <input type="number"  
name="quantity[]" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" /> <input 
type="number"  name="rate[]" id="rate" placeholder="Rate" /> <input 
type="number"  name="amount[]" id="amount" placeholder="Amount" readonly /> 
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_more_fields('+ 
 i +');" style="height:2em; width:3%;">X</button></div>';

objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}

function remove_more_fields(rid) {
   $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
}
</script>


  <div class="form-group fieldgroup" id="more_fields">
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="comp[]" id="component" value="" 
                       placeholder="Product" /> 
   <input type="number"  name="quantity[]" 
   id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity"/>
    <input type="number"  name="rate[]" 
    id="rate" placeholder="Rate" /> 
    <input type="number"  name="amount[]" 
    id="amount" placeholder="Amount" readonly/> 
    <button class="add_field_button" 
    type="button" onclick="more_fields()"> Add</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
    </div>
```

How can I get that result? And I want to calculate the quantity*rate and display the result automatically in Amount field. If I change either quantity or rate, automatically amount will change and display the result. Please suggest me...Thank you.

Comment: Working just fine for me, check here https://jsfiddle.net/noLd8rcs/

Comment: You are right...in jsfiddle its working. While running in Chrome,that is not happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get amount:

```
<div class="form-group fieldgroup" id="more_fields">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="comp[]" id="component" value="" placeholder="Product" />
    <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" onchange="getAmount(this)" />
    <input type="number" name="rate[]" id="rate" placeholder="Rate" onchange="getAmount(this)" />
    <input type="number" name="amount[]" id="amount" placeholder="Amount" readonly/>
    <button class="add_field_button" type="button" onclick="more_fields()"> Add</button>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
<script>
  var i = 1;

  function more_fields() {

    i++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('more_fields');
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass" + i);
    var rdiv = 'removeclass' + i;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="comp[]" id="component" value="" placeholder="Product" /> <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" onchange="getAmount(this)" /> <input type="number"  name="rate[]" id="rate" placeholder="Rate" onchange="getAmount(this)" /> <input type="number"  name="amount[]" id="amount" placeholder="Amount" readonly /> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_more_fields(' + i + ');" style="height:2em; width:3%;">X</button></div>';

    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
  }

  function remove_more_fields(rid) {
    $('.removeclass' + rid).remove();
  }
function getAmount(el)
{
console.log(el.parentElement);
var inputs = el.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('input');

inputs[3].value = (parseInt(inputs[1].value) * parseFloat(inputs[2].value));

}
</script>
```

Here is working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noLd8rcs/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Give the onclick function fro remove button like this - onclick="remove_more_fields(i);" . This would make the function call with value of i being passed to remove_more_fields function.

What I missed telling here is you can include the  entire  divtest.innerHTML definition in - `<div>...</div>`  (note the quote here) , since my editor was showing error for the string spanning multiple lines. This might have triggered the evaluation of i and it worked perfectly fine for me.